# Calling Sharepoint Web Services in jQuery for HTML Applications

Tags: jquery, wcf, sharepoint

While calling lists.asmx from HTML Applications using jQuery, it is working in IE sufficiently, but not working in remaining browsers like Firefox, Safari, Chrome..

SharePoint Custom WCF Services also not working in another browsers while calling from HTML Applications using Jquery.. Getting connecting to the service but showing "data" as null....

Please help me. Thanks in Advance..`

Comment: Calling SharePoint Service from HTML Applications using Jquery.

I was used .getjson,.ajax and Spservices,both are working in IE Browser.But,not working in remaining brosers like firefox,safari and chrome...

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more details. In common is http://spservices.codeplex.com/ a good solution for interacting with the SharePoint webservices by using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are definitely going to need to add more details.  In particular you should be using the JavaScript console in Chrome and Firefox to see what errors you are getting.  Leveraging tools like Fiddler can also help you see what is going on in your system.